# Git gives input/output error on staging. unable to write loose object file

Tags: git

I am getting this error when I try to stage my changes. Couldn't find anything on the internet. I faced this same issue before so did a reclone and the issue got fixed for a while. But got it again after a few days. Any possible fixes or reasons why it's happening?

```
 ❯ git add .
    error: file write error: Input/output error
    fatal: unable to write loose object file
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the error `EIO`, which is generally rendered as "Input/output error", means that your file system or hardware is having a problem.  A healthy file system should never produce this error.

If you're on Linux, you should look at `dmesg` to see what the error from the kernel is and take appropriate action.  That could be an fsck or a replacement of the defective drive.  On other systems, either read the kernel logs or invoke a suitable tool (e.g., Disk Utility on macOS) to find out what's wrong.

This isn't specific to Git; you'll probably see it in other applications as well.

Comment: I ran dmesg and got a bunch of messages on my terminal. Could you specify any term that I should look out for to debug? I am running on linux (Manjaro) and didn't find any issues as such in other applications.

Comment: You're looking for any relevant to your file system (perhaps ext4?) or anything that's associated with a disk (possibly one starting with `sd`, like `sda`, or one starting with `nvme`).  Usually the errors are pretty apparent.